# AWS DMS replication instance unable to connect local machine SQL Server test endpoint

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, database-replication, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate & replicate on-premise SQL Server DB to Aurora DB in AWS. From the AWS docs., it seems it is possible. However, when I tried to implement I faced few problems as below:

- What server name should I provide while setting up the source endpoint (i.e., SQL Server)? Should I specify 'My-Public-IP\DB-Instance-Name'?

I tried that but got 'Test Endpoint Failed' error when trying to test the endpoint.

PS: Same as this - [Connectivity Issue from AWS DMS to local SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588714/connectivity-issue-from-aws-dms-to-local-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can migrate the data from on prem sql server to Aurora.

1. While setting up your source endpoint you should provide IP address of sql server instance in server name field.
2. After this if you are getting timeout error then check NACL ,security group or on-prem sql server instance firewall if any of them is blocking ips